# Task validation in GruntJS

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I would like to add task validation to most of my GruntJS task and I don't know how to achieve it.

What I mean by it: e.g.:

- I have a copy task, I would like to check that exactly 10 files were actually copied;
- That after files minification, there is one files with given name that is not empty;
- That after dir compression, there is one zip files, not empty;

Why I need it: in some scenarios, due to an error, no files were copied and compressed files was empty. It this package is shipped, it would be a big problem.

I know that I can create a custom task, but it would be nice to find it available "out-of-the-box".

Comment: I'm not sure of any such "out-of-the-box" solution, but the custom task shouldn't be very difficult to write.

Comment: It would be pretty easy to fork the standard tasks for these things and add validation to them. They might even merge that back into the main fork, as it sounds pretty useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to close this question with statement: **there's no such feature**.